# Regex to match any number AND any characters between quotes

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I'm confronted to this weird csv formatting, containing non escaped `,` character :

```
   641,"Harstad/Narvik Airport, Evenes","Harstad/Narvik","Norway","EVE","ENEV",68.491302490234,16.678100585938,84,1,"E","Europe/Oslo","airport","OurAirports"
```

I need to return a list like this

```
[641,'Harstad/Narvik Airport Evenes', 'Harstad/Narvik', 'Norway', 'EVE', 'ENEV', 68.491302490234,16.678100585938,84,1, 'E', 'Europe/Oslo', 'airport', 'OurAirports']
```

I have two regex to match part of the string :

- `(\d+\.?\d*)` match numbers
- `(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1` match any characters between two single or double quote

Is there a way to merge the matching into one result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
>>> s = '641,"Harstad/Narvik Airport, Evenes","Harstad/Narvik","Norway","EVE","ENEV",68.491302490234,16.678100585938,84,1,"E","Europe/Oslo","airport","OurAirports"'

>>> csvData = re.findall(r'"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|\d+(?:\.\d+)?', s)
>>> print csvData

['641', '"Harstad/Narvik Airport, Evenes"', '"Harstad/Narvik"', '"Norway"', '"EVE"', '"ENEV"', '68.491302490234', '16.678100585938', '84', '1', '"E"', '"Europe/Oslo"', '"airport"', '"OurAirports"']
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"`: Match a quoted string that allows escaped quotes or any other escaped character inside e.g. `"foo\"bar"` into a single element
- `|`: OR
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`: Match an integer or a decimal number

Comment: Thx, there is a little problem with decimal, ex : 16.678100585938 transformed to '16', '678100585938'